# Asp.net core : getting Cannot access a disposed object error while inserting data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

ASP.NET Core 3.0 with EF Core - I am trying to insert data into a database, but keep getting an error

> Cannot access a disposed object

```cs
private readonly AppDbContext _context;

public erviceController(AppDbContext appDbContext)
{
    _context = appDbContext;
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IFormCollection formCollection)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    CallService();

    return View();
}
```

```cs
public async void CallService()
{
    var product = p1.Value;
    var a = product.first;
    foreach (int Age in a.age)
    {
        foreach (int Gender in a.sex)
        {
            foreach (int Healthclass in a.uclass)
            {
                RequestData requestData = new RequestData()
                {
                    ProductID = 534,
                    STATE = "CO",
                    AGE1 = Age,
                    SEX1 = Gender,
                    UND_CLASS1 = Healthclass,

                };
                string reqedata = requestData.XmlSerializetoString();
                await client.OpenAsync();
                var result2 = await client.RequestAsync(reqedata, partner);
                var requestoutput = new RequestOutputViewmodel();
                requestoutput = result2.DeserializeToObject();
                List<Response> result = new List<Response>();
                if (requestoutput.TotalInitialPremium != null)
                    result.Add(new Response { RunID = "1", Name = "TotalInitialPremium", Result = requestoutput.TotalInitialPremium });
                if (requestoutput.TargetPremium != null)
                    result.Add(new Response { RunID = "1", Name = "TargetPremium", Result = requestoutput.TargetPremium });
                foreach (var results in result)
                {
                    await _context.responses.AddAsync(results);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error at

```
_context.responses.AddAsync(response);
```

Can please anyone help me with this?

Error message:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
>   Object name: 'AppDbContext'

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty clear. Did you check if your code contains some of the suggested causes?

Comment: Or just use synchronous version - `Add` ?

Comment: Don't return void, return Task you can await the call to `CallService`.

Comment: Guru Stron- I used Add but getting same error.

Comment: Crowcoder - i changed void to Task but I am still getting the same error. New change (public async Task CallService(){...})

Comment: @Crowcoder is right. If you fix that and await it properly you should be fine. Make sure you return a Task all the way back to the origin of the call.

Comment: @Silvermind , I updated my code as you mentioned but still getting same error.

Comment: `_context` must be disposed somewhere but it's not in the code you've shown. Do you have that instance in a `using` block someplace?

Comment: I just updated the code

Comment: @Neu The lifecycle of `_context` is still unclear.

Comment: @StackOverthrow Can you please check now?

Comment: Hmm. Is your service scoped in `Startup.cs`? Anything injected with a `DbContext` normally must be scoped because `DbContext` is inherently scoped. I don't remember what happens if you try to inject a `DbContext` into a singleton - if the compiler doesn't complain, you would probably get this error.

Comment: BTW, don't use `Thread.Sleep` in async code, because it actually ties up the thread. Use `Task.Delay`, which leaves the thread free to do other work until it resumes the current method.

Comment: Sounds to me that you have a scoped IDisposable service (client or _context). ASP will call its ```Dispose``` method once the request is completed. Since you are not awaiting on ```CallService``` the request may be completed while the code is still running